# How to get the sum of a field in a materialized view?

Tags: database, oracle, materialized-views

I need to create a materialized view to hold the sum of an amount field from a table that will refresh on update. This is my test scenario:

```
create table mv_test_table ( columnA number, columnB number );

alter table mv_test_table add primary key ( columnA );

create materialized view log on mv_test_table with rowid (columnA, columnB) including new values;

create materialized view mv_view refresh fast on commit with rowid as select sum(columnB) from mv_test_table;
```

mv_view displays the correct sum when I do an insert on mv_test_table, but not when I do an update. What am I missing? I am aware there are some restrictions on what queries you can perform in a MV when using refresh fast.

Or is there another/better approach to achieving the same result? Suggestions appreciated. My queries are getting too bogged down in multiple joins and I'm trying to find a way to pre-calculate some information.

I am working on Oracle database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not a simple view in the case of sum?

Comment: I'm trying to have some information precalculated and saved to cut down on joins performed on the spot.

Comment: can you confirm that your materialized view log shows the updated entry after issuing an UPDATE statement.